# Skip an upcoming scheduled task just once using cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, skip

I'm in the process of automating the daily shutdown of the computers in my school's network. So far I have a batch file which works nicely and I would like to schedule it to run every day at a specific time, however occasionally I may want to skip the task just for the day without permanently disabling it.

I found plenty of information on creating, modifying, disabling and deleting scheduled tasks using cmd, but I found nothing regarding skipping them just once...
Seeing as I am not the only person who would have to skip the task on occasion, it is quite important that it can be skipped using a batch file so that the slightly less computer-savvy people won't have to mess around with the task scheduler.

If the worst comes to the worst I could always have a batch file disable the task and have it schedule a separate task to re-enable the shutdown task after the time it runs at has passed, however it seems like a rather cumbersome solution and I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Create a "flag" file. In the batch file, if the "flag" exist delete it else shutdown the pc.

Comment: @MCND Thanks! That is actually a pretty good solution...

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution is actually to just go to Task properties > Triggers, and change the "first trigger" or start date to a future date, beyond the next  Run.

So if the next Run is Today at 10pm set it to start at 10:01pm  Today or tomorrow. And that's it.